# Compare two dictionaries for matches

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Not sure why this for loop only prints the *values* of the dictionary. **I'd like to do a comparison between two dictionaries and print the matching keys in both.** The matching should be done by key. The keys in this case are the CAS Numbers e.g. `71751412, Abamectin`

```
# create the dictionaries
with open(r'C:\CAS-S.csv') as f:
d = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(f)))
print(d)

with open(r'C:\CAS-B.csv') as f:
g = dict(filter(None, csv.reader(f)))
print(g)

#match keys
for key in d:
  if key in g:
     print (d[key])
```

Comment: What is the input data and what is the expected result?

Comment: You're not sure why it returns _values_, but you want values? If the only problem is that it only prints the values of one dictionary and you want values from both dictionaries, then print them: `print(d[key], g[key])`.

Comment: That loop doesn't return anything, it *prints* something. And it prints *values* because you specifically print the value, not the key.

Comment: Typo sorry @Tigerhawk

Comment: @geckon The input data is the following: [CAS Numbers](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf0ixlbq9ib3o9o/CAS-S.csv?dl=0) and [matching chemicals](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsnnuacdcl5g4e5/CAS-B.csv?dl=0)

Comment: The point is I want it to print the matching keys with the values associated with it. `e.g. a {1 : 'abc' , 2: 'def'} b{1: 'abc', 4: 'lmo'}` returns 1: abc

Comment: Does that entry match because the keys are the same, the values are the same, or both?

Comment: Because the keys match. I'm only looking for a simple comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
# match keys
for key in d:
  if key in g:
     print ('{}: {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks so much.